# How to stop a sibling container from scrolling along with the body?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement some modals in my page using CSS. So far, everything seems to work pretty nicely. The following is the code:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.content {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.fake-content {
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
h1 {
    background-color: white;
}
#section-2 {
    position: sticky;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
}
.content :target {
    scroll-margin-top: 50px;
}

.modal {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    display: none;
    outline: none;
}
.modal:target,
.modal.show {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}
.modal:target ~ .page,
.modal:target ~ .content,
.modal.show ~ .page,
.modal.show ~ .content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.modal-dialog {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    /*position: relative;*/
}


.modal-content {
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

.modal-content .close {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        bottom: 50px;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        bottom: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.modal-dialog::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1em;
}
.modal-dialog::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.mt-0 {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.modal-fullscreen .modal-dialog {

}
.modal-fullscreen .modal-content {
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal" id="modal-1" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            <h2 class="mt-0">Modal 1</h2>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="modal-2" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            <h2 class="mt-0">Modal 2</h2>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal modal-fullscreen" id="modal-3" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            <h2 class="mt-0">Modal 3 (Full)</h2>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal modal-fullscreen" id="modal-4" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            <br />
            <h2 class="mt-0">Modal 4 (Full)</h2>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page">
    <!-- Header start -->
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <!-- Header end -->

    <!-- Content start -->
    <div class="content">

        <!-- Section 1 start -->
        <h1 id="section-1">
            Section 1
            <a href="#section-1">#</a>
        </h1>
        <button type="button">Use JavaScript</button>
        <br /><br />
        <a href="#modal-1">Modal 1</a>
        <a href="#modal-2">Modal 2</a>
        <a href="#modal-3">Modal 3</a>
        <a href="#modal-4">Modal 4</a>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <!-- Section 1 end -->

        <!-- Section 2 start -->
        <h1 id="section-2">
            Section 2
            <a href="#section-2">#</a>
        </h1>
        <a href="#modal-1">Modal 1</a>
        <a href="#modal-2">Modal 2</a>
        <a href="#modal-3">Modal 3</a>
        <a href="#modal-4">Modal 4</a>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <!-- Section 2 end -->

    </div>
    <!-- Content end -->
</div>
```

As you can see, the basic functionality works quite nicely. Unfortunately, one issue is this block of CSS:

```
.modal:target ~ .page,
.modal:target ~ .content,
.modal.show ~ .page,
.modal.show ~ .content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I mainly added the fixed position to stop the `.page` from scrolling when a modal is open. It works well enough, but every time the modal is opened, the page scroll is reset to the top. Is there any way to fix this without JavaScript? Perhaps I'm not looking at this the right way. Therefore, what is the right way to stop a sibling container from scrolling?

Comment: add `overflow-y: hidden` and possibly `max-height: 100vh`  to the `<body>` element when a modal is open

Comment: @admcfajn But how would you target a parent node with CSS?

Comment: i wouldn't it's not possible. generally i'd trigger the display of the modal by toggling a css class via javascript. Sorry, i was answering the title of your question, not the footnotes :) Using a `~` or `+` from outside of the element you want to modify is a good way to go sans-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I think will work for you. Here's what I did:

- Gave the modals a `fixed` position, with `overflow: auto`. This enables the modal to sit atop the rest of the content so that it won't scroll with it, and then lets the content of the modal determine the scrollability within it.
- Put a `.wrapper` div outside of `.page` and gave it `overflow: auto`. This enables us to change the scroll behavior of the content without needing to access `body` with JavaScript.
- Positioned `.wrapper` to appear underneath the header and take up the rest of the page height
- Moved the header outside of `page` so that it isn't hiding the scrollbar of the `.wrapper` div.
- Set `.wrapper` to `overflow: hidden` when the modal is open, so that it doesn't lose its scroll position, and so we don't see 2 scrollbars when modals are open.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.content {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.fake-content {
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
h1 {
    background-color: white;
}
#section-2 {
    position: sticky;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
}
.content :target {
    scroll-margin-top: 50px;
}

.modal {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    display: none;
    outline: none;
}
.modal:target,
.modal.show {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}
.modal:target ~ .page,
.modal:target ~ .content,
.modal.show ~ .page,
.modal.show ~ .content {
}

.modal-dialog {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    /*position: relative;*/
}


.modal-content {
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

.modal-content .close {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        bottom: 50px;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        bottom: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.modal-dialog::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1em;
}
.modal-dialog::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.wrapper
{
position: relative;
top: 50px;
height: calc(100vh - 50px);
overflow: auto;
}
.modal.show ~ .wrapper
{
overflow: hidden;
}

.mt-0 {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.modal-fullscreen .modal-dialog {

}
.modal-fullscreen .modal-content {
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal" id="modal-1" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            <h2 class="mt-0">Modal 1</h2>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="modal-2" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            <h2 class="mt-0">Modal 2</h2>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal modal-fullscreen" id="modal-3" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            <h2 class="mt-0">Modal 3 (Full)</h2>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal modal-fullscreen" id="modal-4" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            <br />
            <h2 class="mt-0">Modal 4 (Full)</h2>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
            <div class="fake-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- Header start -->
    <div class="header">
    </div>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="page">
    <!-- Header end -->

    <!-- Content start -->
    <div class="content">

        <!-- Section 1 start -->
        <h1 id="section-1">
            Section 1
            <a href="#section-1">#</a>
        </h1>
        <button type="button">Use JavaScript</button>
        <br /><br />
        <a href="#modal-1">Modal 1</a>
        <a href="#modal-2">Modal 2</a>
        <a href="#modal-3">Modal 3</a>
        <a href="#modal-4">Modal 4</a>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <!-- Section 1 end -->

        <!-- Section 2 start -->
        <h1 id="section-2">
            Section 2
            <a href="#section-2">#</a>
        </h1>
        <a href="#modal-1">Modal 1</a>
        <a href="#modal-2">Modal 2</a>
        <a href="#modal-3">Modal 3</a>
        <a href="#modal-4">Modal 4</a>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <div class="fake-content"></div>
        <!-- Section 2 end -->

    </div>
    <!-- Content end -->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although I wasn't looking to change the markup, I guess this will have to do.